# Proof that $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,1)} e^{xy} = 1$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, proof-verification, epsilon-delta

Here is my proof:

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given. There exists $\delta >0$ such that $$|e^{xy}-1| < \epsilon$$ whenever $0<|x|<\delta$ and  $0<|y-1|<\delta$.

Using exponential series, we write $$|e^{xy}-1|=|(1+xy+\frac{x^2y^2}{2!}+...)-1|$$ $$=|xy+\frac{x^2y^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3y^3}{3!}+...|$$ $$\le|xy|+|\frac{x^2y^2}{2!}|+|\frac{x^3y^3}{3!}|+...$$ $$\le|xy|+|x^2y^2|+|x^3y^3|+...$$
$$\lt\delta|y|+\delta^2|y|^2+\delta^3|y|^3+...$$

Let $\delta\le\frac12\implies\frac12\lt y\lt\frac32$ $$\therefore|e^{xy}-1|\lt\frac32\delta+(\frac32\delta)^2+(\frac32\delta)^3+...$$ $$= \frac{3\delta}{2-3\delta}$$

So, we choose $$\delta = min\{\frac12,\frac{2\epsilon}{3(\epsilon+1)}\}$$

$$\implies|e^{xy}-1|\lt\epsilon$$whenever$$0<|x|<\delta $$ and $$0<|y-1|<\delta$$

Q.E.D.

I would also like to know if there are any other ways to prove this.

Comment: Do you have to use $\epsilon$-$\delta$? Otherwise, just note that $xy \mapsto e^{xy}$ is continuous.

Comment: No. Other methods are also fine. Just wanted to use $\epsilon-\delta$ for the mental exercise :)

Comment: @ConnorHarris That approach uses $\epsilon$-$\delta$ too. Twice, actually. It's just usually hidden behind "We already know this general result".

Comment: @DonThousand I'm not sure I follow. Isn't epsilon-delta the way to show that a limit exists? Or is there a catch to it? Can you please provide references?

Comment: @DonThousand I see. Would taking the circular neighbourhood of the point (0,1) work then? If it would, I took the square neighbourhood because it follows from the circular neighbourhood. If we observe that $0<|x|\le\sqrt{x^2+(y-1)^2}<\delta$ and similarly for $|y-1|$. If I'm wrong, what is right way to prove that the limit exists?

Comment: @DonThousand There is nothing wrong with assuming $\delta$ is the same for $x$ and $y$. You're just looking at all points in a square centered around $(0,1)$ rather than a rectangle. We are not looking at just the corners of the squares (in which case rectangles would indeed be necessary).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you use the composition theorem 
$$
f:(x,y)\to xy,\ g:z\to e^z
$$ 
with 
$$
f: \mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R},\ g:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}
$$ 
For the mental exercise, it is very rewarding and I can understand it. Then I advise you to decompose this composition (i.e. general result but with $\epsilon,\delta$).
For example, first for a given $\epsilon$, find the $\delta$ corresponding to the continuity of $g$, then the $\delta_1,\delta_2$ corresponding to the continuity of $f$.

**About your proof** It seems clever (I only overlooked it, I must go into details), but can be made more generic by decomposing

1. For every given $\epsilon>0$, find $\delta>0$ such that $|z|<\delta\Longrightarrow |e^z-1|<\epsilon$ (you can reuse your argument proving that $|e^z-1|\leq e^{|z|}-1$)

   For every given $\delta>0$ find $\delta_i>0,\ i=1,2$ such that 
   $$
   |x|<\delta_1\mbox{ and } |y-1|<\delta_2\Longrightarrow |xy|<\delta
   $$

Comment: 1. We can write $e^{|z|}-1<e^\delta-1$ and choose $\delta=ln(\epsilon+1)$.

2. I am a bit doubtful about this one. We can write $|xy|=|x||y|<\delta_1|y|$. Let $\delta_2<1$, we can write $|xy|<2\delta_1$. We can then choose $\delta_1=\epsilon/2$ and $\delta_2=1$. Or $\delta = min\{1,\epsilon/2\}$. The choice of $\delta$ is what I am a bit doubtful about.
Also why choose a rectangular neighbourhood?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to let $\delta_2\le1$ instead of $\delta_2<1$. A typo on my part.

Comment: [Also why choose a rectangular neighbourhood ?] ---> well this is debatable (just tradition, simplicity and genericity). For the first $\delta$, I would rather choose any $\delta$ within $]0,ln(\epsilon+1)[$.